# How to create/access Hive tables with external Metastore on additional Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I want to perform some data transformation in Hive with Azure Data Factory (v1) running a Azure HDInsight On Demand cluster (3.6).

Since the HDInsight On Demand cluster gets destroyed after some idle time and I want/need to keep the metadata about the Hive tables (e.g. partitions), I also configured an external Hive metastore, using a Azure SQL Server database.

Now I want to store all production data on a separate storage account than the one "default" account, where Data Factory and HDInsight also create containers for logging and other runtime data.

So I have the following resources:

- Data Factory with HDInsight On Demand (as a linked service)
- SQL Server and database for Hive metastore (configured in HDInsight On Demand)
- Default storage account to be used by Data Factory and HDInsight On Demand cluster (blob storage, general purpose v1)
- Additional storage account for data ingress and Hive tables (blob storage, general purpose v1)

Except the Data Factory, which is in location `North Europe`, all resources are in the same location `West Europe`, which should be fine (the HDInsight cluster must be in the same location as any storage accounts you want to use). All Data Factory related deployment is done using the [DataFactoryManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactories.datafactorymanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet) API.

An example Hive script (deployed as a HiveActivity in Data Factory) looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example_table (
  deviceId string,
  createdAt timestamp,
  batteryVoltage double,
  hardwareVersion string,
  softwareVersion string,
)
PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string) -- year and month from createdAt
CLUSTERED BY (deviceId) INTO 256 BUCKETS
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION 'wasb://container@additionalstorage.blob.core.windows.net/example_table'
TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');

INSERT INTO TABLE example_table PARTITIONS (year, month) VALUES ("device1", timestamp "2018-01-22 08:57:00", 2.7, "hw1.32.2", "sw0.12.3");
```

Following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/compute-linked-services) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-adf), this should be rather straightforward: Simply add the new storage account as an additional linked service (using the `additionalLinkedServiceNames` property).

However, this resulted in the following exceptions when a Hive script tried to access a table stored on this account:

```
IllegalStateException Error getting FileSystem for wasb : org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.KeyProviderException: ExitCodeException exitCode=2: Error reading S/MIME message
139827842123416:error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:not enough data:a_d2i_fp.c:247:
139827842123416:error:0D0D106E:asn1 encoding routines:B64_READ_ASN1:decode error:asn_mime.c:192:
139827842123416:error:0D0D40CB:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:asn1 parse error:asn_mime.c:517:
```

[Some googling told me](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19123?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) that this happens, when the key provider is not configured correctly (i.e. the exceptions is thrown because it tries to decrypt the key even though it is not encrypted). After manually setting `fs.azure.account.keyprovider.<storage_name>.blob.core.windows.net` to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.SimpleKeyProvider` it seemed to work for reading and "simple" writing of data to tables, but failed again when the metastore got involved (creating a table, adding new partitions, ...):

```
ERROR exec.DDLTask: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:783)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4434)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:316)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
[...]
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result$create_table_with_environment_context_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:38593)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result$create_table_with_environment_context_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:38561)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$create_table_with_environment_context_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:38487)
  at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1103)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.create_table_with_environment_context(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:1089)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2203)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.create_table_with_environment_context(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:99)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:736)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:724)
  [...]
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:178)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.createTable(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:777)
  ... 24 more
```

I tried googling that again, but had no luck finding something usable. I think it may have to do something with the fact, that the metastore service is running separately from Hive and for some reason does not have access to the configured storage account keys... but to be honest, I think this should all just work without manually tinkering with the Hadoop/Hive configuration.

So, my question is: What am I doing wrong and how is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you also add the hadoop-azure.jar and the azure-storage-5.4.0.jar to your Hadoop Classpath export in your hadoop-env.sh.

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop-client/hadoop-azure.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-client/lib/azure-storage-5.4.0.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH

And you will need to add the storage key via the following parameter in your core-site. 
fs.azure.account.key.{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net

When you create your DB and table you need to specify the location using your storage account and the user id
Create table {Tablename}
...
LOCATION 'wasbs://{container}@{storageaccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{filepath}'

If you still have problems after trying the above check to see whether the storage account is a V1 or V2. We had an issue where the V2 storage account did not work with our version of HDP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I am using Azure HDInsight and deploy it using the DataFactoryManagementClient (C#/.NET), I cannot change the classpath (AFAIK) and would assume that Microsoft does include those jars already. Also, accessing the "default" storage account works as expected. The account keys are already in the core-site.xml (this is handled by the HDInsight deployment process) and I am using `LOCATION 'wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/table'` already, which works with the default account. The storage account is "general purpose v1".

Comment: Have you tried wasbs? You have just wasb in your location.